# Math & php: FAST sort of an array [1..N] in a special way

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, math, optimization

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., N);
```

Also there is a number `D = 10%`. What is the fastest way to sort the array in such way that:

```
$sorted_array = {a[i]}
```

contains exactly the elements of `$array` in a mixed order, but also:

```
abs(a[i + 1] - a[i]) >= N * 10%
```

for any `[i]` and look randomized as much as possible.

For example,

```
// assume D = 25%
$array = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

// so the difference between any neighbors is >= 4 = 10 * 25%.
$sorted_array = array(4, 8, 3, 7, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10);
```

Of course if `D` is large, it is impossible to sort the array I want. I don't need the 100% perfect result, but I want the numbers to look "randomized" and most of them to be different at least for 10%.

I have a strange task but it has a practical area to use. I want to extract randomized lines from the image and they should be different as much as possible. Of course, the neighbor lines on the digital images (photos etc) look very similar.

Did I explain it properly?

Comment: This is not a simple task, I suggest you try something first, then people may help you to improve it

Comment: First of all it is important that the !absolute value! of a[i + 1] - a[i] part must be bigger or equal to N * D, otherwise you can never ever go from 8 to three or so, secondly if it must look randomized it gets far more complicated :S

Comment: Thanks for pointing about the absolute value. Just fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's not a good idea just to provide code, but I was intrigued by this question. Here's how I would do it:

```
$d = 0.3;
$random = array();

// Populate the original array
for ($n=1; $n <= 10; $n++) {
    $arr[] = $n;
}

$count = count($arr);

// Loop through array
foreach (array_keys($arr) as $key) {
    if (!isset($prev_key)) {
        $prev_key = array_rand($arr);
    }
    $possibles = array(); // This stores the possible values
    echo "Trying: $prev_key";
    echo ":\n";

    // Loop through the array again and populate $possibles with all possible
    // values based on the previous values
    foreach (array_keys($arr) as $n) {
        if ($arr[$n] < $prev_key - $count * $d || $arr[$n] > $prev_key + $count * $d) {
            $possibles[] = $n;
            echo $arr[$n]." is valid\n";
        }
        else {
            echo $arr[$n];
            echo " outside range\n";
        }
    }

    // If there is nothing outside that range, just return the remaining values
    if (count($possibles) == 0) {
        $possibles = array_keys($arr);
        echo "Nothing within range so just returning whole array\n";
    }
    echo "\n";

    // Choose random value from the possible values array
    $rand_key = $possibles[array_rand($possibles)];

    $random[] = $arr[$rand_key];
    $prev_key = $arr[$rand_key];

    // Unset this value from the original array since we can only use the
    // values once
    unset($arr[$rand_key]);
}

print_r($random);
```

This will produce output like this:

```
Trying: 8:
1 is valid
2 is valid
3 is valid
4 is valid
5 outside range
6 outside range
7 outside range
8 outside range
9 outside range
10 outside range

Trying: 2:
1 outside range
3 outside range
4 outside range
5 outside range
6 is valid
7 is valid
8 is valid
9 is valid
10 is valid

Trying: 9:
1 is valid
3 is valid
4 is valid
5 is valid
6 outside range
7 outside range
8 outside range
10 outside range

Trying: 5:
1 is valid
3 outside range
4 outside range
6 outside range
7 outside range
8 outside range
10 is valid

Trying: 10:
1 is valid
3 is valid
4 is valid
6 is valid
7 outside range
8 outside range

Trying: 4:
1 outside range
3 outside range
6 outside range
7 outside range
8 is valid

Trying: 8:
1 is valid
3 is valid
6 outside range
7 outside range

Trying: 3:
1 outside range
6 outside range
7 is valid

Trying: 7:
1 is valid
6 outside range

Trying: 1:
6 is valid

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 6
)
```

The only drawback is that since it randomly gets rows, there is a chance that the values near the end may not be outside the defined range. By my tests, this happens to about 4% using the above `$d = 0.25` and 1000 values. One way to get around this is just to insert these values back in at random places instead of appending them like I have done.

Also note, this method is not that efficient. It has to loop through the array `count($arr) ^ 2` times. So for 1000 values, you're looking at 1,000,000 iterations. Fortunately the array gets progressively smaller.

Comment: It's funny how an awesome answer like this gets 1 or 2 upvotes while something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18069251/811240) gets 6... Oh Stack Overflow, you crazy website.

Comment: If I could I would add +10. Thank you for your answer. I expected there will be more answers and a big discussion. My fault I didn't put my code (doesn't exist yet).
Thank you.