# I want to echo __FILE__ name without path. I just want to name of page for example: index.php

Tags: php, path, filenames

> echo **__*FILE*__**;

gives me:
C:\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\FOLDERNAME\index.php

I just want to get file name without its path.
I want to get index.php on its own.

Any ideas?

Comment: `echo basename(__FILE__);`

Comment: Has been asked before, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222644/php-echo-current-filename-without-extension

Comment: @garrettmurray - That page has been removed by SO.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
echo basename(__FILE__);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function, then you can get `filename` via `basename`

```
$path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);

echo $path_parts['basename'];
```